# View javascript variables and their values in one page

Tags: javascript, variables, firebug

Is there any way to see all the javascript variables that are being used by a script (or scripts) in a website page? I have Firebug installed and I've been playing around with it and searching online but I can't find an answer.

Comment: There's the 'watch' option in Firebug's script section, which lets you watch live updates of variable values, but you have to add those variables to the list yourself.

Comment: You can see all the 'global' ones...

Comment: In the `DOM` tab of Firebug you can see all global variables, if that's what you want.

Comment: There's no way to see all variables set in all functions, in all scopes, in real-time, if that's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 2):

You have to have a script on your page, then you open the script in firebug and set a breakpoint on one of the lines, then refresh your page.  You should then see a list of all the variables on the right.